# How to check values in columns in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array,

```
> [[  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]
 ...
 [  0 255   0 255   0]
 [  0 255   0   0   0]
 [  0 255   0   0   0]]
```

I would like to check values in each column of this 2d numpy array - whether or not there are more than one column with alternating 0 and 255 values

Example column

```
>   [[  0 0   0 255   0]
     [  0 255 0   0   0]
     [  0 255 0   0   0]
     [  0 255 0   0   0]
     [  0 0   0   0   0]
     [  0 0   0   0   0]
     [  0 0   0   0   0]
     [  0 0   0   0   0]
     [  0 255 0   0   0]
     [  0 255 0   0   0]
     [  0 255 0   0   0]
     [  0 255 0   0   0]
     [  0 255 0   0   0]]
```

In the above example, column two has alternating 0 and 255 values, hence, the output should be that this numpy array has one column with these alternating values

Comment: The fourth column also has alternating 0 and 255 values, no?

Comment: It has, but I will add a threshold of the occurences of 255 and 0s

Answer (score 1):

```
np.sum(np.count_nonzero(np.diff(a, axis=0), axis=0) > 1)
```

Comment: Wow, beautiful.

Comment: Does it check all the columns of the array?

Comment: I need the number of columns that have a majority of alternating 0s and 255s.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand how the second column has alternate values of 0 and 255 but here is an idea...

```
>>> unique, counts = numpy.unique(numpy.transpose(nd_a)[0], return_counts=True)
>>> counts
array([13], dtype=int64)
>>> unique, counts = numpy.unique(numpy.transpose(nd_a)[1], return_counts=True)
>>> counts
array([5, 8], dtype=int64)
```

if len(nd_a) is same as counts then its not alternating but if values are somewhat similar(e.g. 5 and 8 take 5/13 and 8/13) then its alternating.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "alternating" means that the same value appears more than once without being adjacent to its other occurrences:

If you take the `diff` of each row's value with its successor (per column), there should be three possible values: `0`, `255`, `-255`.  Only columns with alternating values will have both `255` and `-255`.  Testing for the presence of these two `diff` values (using a few Pandas methods) will give you the answer.

```
import pandas as pd

def check_alt(data):
    return (pd.DataFrame(data)
            .diff()
            .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
            .loc[[-255,255]]
            .notnull()
            .all()
            .sum())

check_alt(a) # 2
check_alt(b) # 4
```

Data:

```
a = [[0,0,0,255,0],
[0,255,0,0,255],
[0,255,0,0,0],
[0,255,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,255,0,0,0],
[0,255,0,0,0],
[0,255,0,0,0],
[0,255,0,0,0],
[0,255,0,0,0]]

b = [[0,0,0,255,0],
[255,255,0,0,255],
[0,0,0,255,0]]
```

The nested list `a` is your example data.  I also included an extra array, `b`, to demonstrate the edge case where there are only constantly alternating values (i.e. every next value is not the one before it).  The expected count of alternating columns for `b` is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution;

```
import numpy as np

#construct numpy array
c = np.zeros((15,5)) # Pre-allocate matrix


#populate some columns with number patterns

c[1:4,1] = 255
c[8:13,1] = 255

c[1,3] = 255

c[1:4,4] = 255
c[7:12,4] = 255

OUT = np.empty(shape=[15,0])

for ni in range(0,c.shape[1]):
    #work on column ni from c
    a = c[:,ni] #work on array a
    b = np.diff(a) #differene between neighbouring elements
    d = np.where(b != 0) #work out where the transitions from 0->255 or 255->0 are

    #work out what constitutes an alternating pattern (you may want to change the logic)
    if np.size(d) > 2:
        #this column from C has been deemed to have an alternating pattern
        OUT = np.append(OUT, c[:,ni:ni+1], axis=1) # add the column to the OUT array
```